# How can I remove all characters after x number of characters in a string for all rows of a data set?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a column in my data set where I need to remove all characters after 6 characters. Each row of this column has strings of different lengths, so I am unable to just take a set amount off of the end. I searched online and was only able to find solutions to removing the first, or last, couple characters, but nothing for removing everything except the first characters.

This is what the data set looks like:

```
   ComputerName     DaysCheckIn
0   CTE14001        160
1   CLB209LT11      144
2   WPK-REG         135
3   ATB190S01       91
```

I saw solutions that use `map()`, `lambda`, and `strip()` to remove strings, but I am not sure if I am on the right track with what I need to do with them.

Comment: If you are sure all of the entries are at least 6 characters, use a string slice `string = string[:6]`. If some are less, do `string = [:min(len(string), 6)]`. Obviously this is just a generic example

Comment: @NChauhan `min()` isn't necessary.

Comment: @MarkTolonen If the length is less than 6, `s[:6]` will raise an `IndexError` won’t it?

Comment: @NChauhan No, try it (and see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String slicing.  This syntax will keep at most 6 characters:

```
>>> s = '1234567890'
>>> s = s[:6]
>>> s
'123456'
>>> s = '1234'
>>> s = s[:6]
>>> s
'1234'
```

And specifically, if using `pandas`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
>>> df
  ComputerName  DaysCheckIn
0     CTE14001          160
1  CLB209LT11S          144
2      WPK-REG          135
3    ATB190S01           91
>>> df['ComputerName']
0       CTE14001
1    CLB209LT11S
2        WPK-REG
3      ATB190S01
>>> # Take strings in named column and truncate to no more than 6 characters
>>> df['ComputerName'] = df['ComputerName'].str[:6]
>>> df
  ComputerName  DaysCheckIn
0       CTE140          160
1       CLB209          144
2       WPK-RE          135
3       ATB190           91
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, `myString[:6]` will give you the first six characters of a string.